# Why do I get this error when trying to set up a class variable

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm new to PHP so maybe I am overlooking something here but the following:

```
class someClass {

    var $id = $_GET['id'];

    function sayHello() {

        echo "Hello";

    }

}
```

gives the following error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\files\classes.php on line 13**

If instead of $_GET['id'] I set the variable $id to a string, everything is fine though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign anything except constants to a class member in that way without using a constructor.

See [the manual](http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> declaration [of a property] may include an initialization, **but this initialization must be a constant value**--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

The alternative method of doing it is [to use a constructor](http://php.oregonstate.edu/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) to set the value:

```
class someClass {

    var $id;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->id = $_GET['id'];
    }

    function sayHello() {
        echo "Hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign your variable in a constructor

```
class someClass {

    function __construct() {
        $this->id = $_GET['id'];
    }

}
```